# Is there a warning on corrupt Solr cores in core admin?

Tags: solr

The core admin at `http://0.0.0.0:8983/solr/admin/cores` gives the following output. Can I get **information on corrupt data or other bad signs** within this information?

For example, can I take `result['status']['collection1']['uptime']` as proof that collection is healthy?

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "defaultCoreName":"collection1",
  "initFailures":{},
  "status":{
    "collection1":{
      "name":"collection1",
      "isDefaultCore":true,
      "instanceDir":"solr/collection1/",
      "dataDir":"solr/collection1/data/",
      "config":"solrconfig.xml",
      "schema":"schema.xml",
      "startTime":"2013-01-14T13:20:38.775Z",
      "uptime":142141,
      "index":{
        "numDocs":0,
        "maxDoc":0,
        "version":1,
        "segmentCount":0,
        "current":true,
        "hasDeletions":false,
        "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory:NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/home/jesvin/dev/apache-solr-4.0.0/example/solr/collection1/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@f2bf5b; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)",
        "userData":{},
        "sizeInBytes":65,
        "size":"65 bytes"}}}}
```